# A calendar of future EO satellites pass based on location

Tags: geospatial, calendar

There are several Earth Observation satellites with known orbit paths and return time. (ex: Landsat 8: 16 days, Sentinel-2: 12 days).

Is there a shared calendar or a web-app that shows you future passing dates for a specific location on earth, be it Path/Row, UTM Granule, or a simple Coordinate ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for ? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/satellite-tracker/id306260378?mt=8

What about this ? http://www.n2yo.com/

http://science.nasa.gov/iSat/?group=SMD

You might want to google "Satellites" to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that there might be a better resource for this, but one that I know off the top of my head is the Satellite Simulation Center from NASA :  http://sscweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/

It's more about where satellites are at a given time vs. when (or which) satellite would pass over a given area.  The location searching that they have is more about satellites relative to the magnetic field (as opposed to geographic).

It's quite possible that someone from the earth sciences would know how to find this out, but I don't work with those folks.